# Multiple packages in android project

Tags: android, android-manifest

Have a look at my AndroidMenifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.myapp"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity      android:name="com.myapp.activities.exercisesetsactivity.ExercisesetsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activities.mainactivity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <!--intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter-->
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.myapp.services.guideservice.GuideService"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Initially, I had MainActivity was my default activity. Later I tried to change it to ExercisesetsActivity. That is where I started getting below error in my logcat.

```
 > 
    01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.activities.exercisesetsactivity.ExercisesetsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at com.myapp.activities.exercisesetsactivity.ExercisesetsActivity.<init>(ExercisesetsActivity.java:24)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
        01-22 22:09:51.831: E/AndroidRuntime(22676):    ... 11 more
```

If I change it to MainActivity, it works fine. However, I want ExercisesetsActivity to come up first.

```
package com.myapp.activities.exercisesetsactivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.myapp.R;
import com.myapp.activities.mainactivity.MainActivity;
import com.myapp.businessclasses.Exercisesetlist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExercisesetsActivity extends Activity {
**private Exercisesetlist myExerciseSetList = new Exercisesetlist(this.getApplicationContext());**

private class currentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public currentListAdapter() {
        super(ExercisesetsActivity.this, R.layout.activity_exercisesetlist,
                ExercisesetsActivity.this.myExerciseSetList.setNames);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_exercisesetlist, parent,
                false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvItems);

        String strContent = ExercisesetsActivity.this.myExerciseSetList.setNames
                .get(position);
        label.setText(strContent);
        label.setTag(position);
        label.setOnClickListener(exerciseClickListner);

        return row;
    }

}

private android.view.View.OnClickListener exerciseClickListner = new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();

        Intent intent = new Intent(ExercisesetsActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ExercisesetsActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.EXERCISESETID),
                ExercisesetsActivity.this.myExerciseSetList.setIDs.get(pos));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};

// This is temporary
public void copyDBifnotexists() {
    String DATABASE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() + "/myapp/data/";
    String DATABSE_NAME = "db.db";

    File folders = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
    File file = new File(folders, DATABSE_NAME);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        folders.mkdirs();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(
                    R.raw.db);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercisesetlist);

    // This is temporary
    copyDBifnotexists();

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExerciselist);
    lv.setAdapter(new currentListAdapter());
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `ExercisesetsActivity` file code ?

Comment: As @Grishu said, post your code and highlight line no. 24 in it.

Comment: Try this way android:name="com.myapp.activities.mainactivity.ExercisesetsActivity" if possible then post code of ExercisesetsActivity class

Comment: This is line# 24. **private Exercisesetlist myExerciseSetList = new Exercisesetlist(this.getApplicationContext());**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Exercisesetlist myExerciseSetList = new Exercisesetlist(this.getApplicationContext());
```

I am Not Sure but it likely because without calling OnCreate() method you will not get context of that Activity. so try to initialize this inside OnCreate() method like as Below and see what happens.

```
private Exercisesetlist myExerciseSetList;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercisesetlist);

    myExerciseSetList = new Exercisesetlist(this.getApplicationContext());

}
```

Hope it will Help you.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the instance of your `Exercisesetlist myExerciseSetList` in your `onCreate()` method of the activity as below:

> ```
>  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>          setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercisesetlist);
>          myExerciseSetList = new Exercisesetlist(this.getApplicationContext());
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at attempting to answer this one. I am assuming, `Exercisesetlist` is a helper class (setter / getter).

Change this:

```
private Exercisesetlist myExerciseSetList = new Exercisesetlist(this.getApplicationContext());
```

To this:

```
public class ExercisesetsActivity extends Activity {
    private Exercisesetlist myExerciseSetList;
    ....
    ....
}
```

And:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercisesetlist);

    // This is temporary
    copyDBifnotexists();

    // INSTANTIATE THE Exercisesetlist INSTANCE
    myExerciseSetList = new Exercisesetlist(ExercisesetsActivity.this);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExerciselist);
    lv.setAdapter(new currentListAdapter());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file, in activity tag you specified android:name as

```
        android:name="com.myapp.activities.exercisesetsactivity.ExercisesetsActivity"
```

remove com.myapp and specify as

```
      android:name=".activities.exercisesetsactivity.ExercisesetsActivity"
```

then you will not get the error.

Comment: This didn't help. I already tried. Initializing "myExerciseSetList" in oncreate method worked. I appreciate your effort.